# How to prevent second click on radio button if it was already clicked in Android?

Tags: java, android

I want to stop the second click on a `RadioButton`, when someone has already clicked on a `RadioButton` in a `RadioGroup`. If someone clicks 2 times, the user not able to change that selected click. I am trying to prevent that with a `boolean` but it doesn't work. Where am I wrong?

**This is my code:**

```
radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
            rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);

            user_radio_answer = (String) rb.getText();

            rb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                private boolean isChecked = true;
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (isChecked) {
                        if (rb.isChecked() ) {

                            isChecked = false;
                        }
                    }
                    if (correct_answer1.equals(user_radio_answer)) {
                        rb.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct ☺ : " + user_radio_answer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Answer :( ..Correct Answer :  " + correct_answer1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        rb.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF5733"));
                        answer1 = rb_answer1.getText().toString();
                        answer2 = rb_answer2.getText().toString();
                        answer3 = rb_answer3.getText().toString();
                        answer4 = rb_answer4.getText().toString();

                        if (answer1.equals(correct_answer1)) {
                            rb_answer1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        }
                        if (answer2.equals(correct_answer1)) {
                            rb_answer2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        }
                        if (answer3.equals(correct_answer1)) {
                            rb_answer3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        }
                        if (answer4.equals(correct_answer1)) {
                            rb_answer4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                        }


                    }

                    new RadioHttpAsyncTask().execute("http:xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx");
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: you can disable the button, but that would also have an impact on the UI. you could also keep a flag that is set/checked within your actual perform method to see if you want to execute the code

Comment: use a integer lets say counter , decrease its value,increase and clear it

Comment: May be problem is that you are setting `OnClickListener` inside `onCheckedChanged`. It means after any check change your current `RadioButton` cleared all informations it had before in your `isChecked` field. Try to set it outside `onCheckedChanged` method.

Comment: Okay thanks for suggestion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add two methods and then call them when needed. You can add a condition, if the radiobutton is checked then disable the group and if it is not checked then set it to enabled. When you clear your radiogroup you can also set buttons enabled.

```
public void disableRG() {
    for(int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++){
        ((RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(false);
    }
}

 public void enableRG() {
        for(int i = 0; i < radioGroup.getChildCount(); i++){
            ((RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(i)).setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it will prevent the second click

Comment: It works 100% as per the requirement! Thank you, sir, for the suggestion :)

Answer (score 2):

Just remember if they have answered the question, and remember the view (RadioButton) that spawned the first answer, and check that RadioButton again whenever a RadioButton is clicked.  This assumes all RadioButtons in the RadioGroup have the same `onClick` method.

```
boolean answered = false;
RadioButton radioAnswer;
public void answer1(View view) {
    if (!answered) {
        radioAnswer = (RadioButton) view;
        answered = true;
    } else {
        radioAnswer.setChecked(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it after click to stop listening to click events

```
rb.setEnabled(false);
```

Edit:

Or you can remove click listener once it is already clicked

```
rb.setOnClickListener(null);
```

Comment: I don't want to enable it, just want to stop the second click on any radio button in that group, if it already clicked once.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can set a global boolean flag.

```
  `private boolean alreadyChecked = false;
   radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new    
   RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // checkedId is the RadioButton selected
        rb = (RadioButton) findViewById(checkedId);

        user_radio_answer = (String) rb.getText();

        if (!alreadyChecked) {

          rb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

              private boolean isChecked = true;
              @Override
              public void onClick(View v) {

                  if (isChecked) {
                      if (rb.isChecked() ) {

                          isChecked = false;
                      }
                  }
                  if (correct_answer1.equals(user_radio_answer)) {
                      rb.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                      //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct ☺ : " + user_radio_answer, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  } else {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Incorrect Answer :( ..Correct Answer :  " + correct_answer1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      rb.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF5733"));
                      answer1 = rb_answer1.getText().toString();
                      answer2 = rb_answer2.getText().toString();
                      answer3 = rb_answer3.getText().toString();
                      answer4 = rb_answer4.getText().toString();

                      if (answer1.equals(correct_answer1)) {
                          rb_answer1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                      }
                      if (answer2.equals(correct_answer1)) {
                          rb_answer2.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                      }
                      if (answer3.equals(correct_answer1)) {
                          rb_answer3.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                      }
                      if (answer4.equals(correct_answer1)) {
                          rb_answer4.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                      }


                  }

                  new RadioHttpAsyncTask().execute("http:xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx");
              }
              alreadyChecked = true;
          });
         }
    }
});`
```

Comment: Thank you! Matthias Neubert. It has solved my 50% problem but not the whole problem. Still, the radio button is on clicked mode which I want to stop.